# Sum value from multiple JSON data in postgress sql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have datatype JSON stored on postgress db, e g. column:jsondata.

Each row on db table represent one JSON data of the same format,e.q.

```json
{
  "ID": "001",
  "Name": "Britney",
  "DebtAmount": "100.23"
}
```

There are multiple records with the above data with different ID.

How do I do JSON query to get the total sum of Debt Amount accross multiple records?

Thanks alot for your help.
If there is already existing solution, please point me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`json_each_text()`** function in order to extract key-value pairs from the JSON object after fixing the current value in order to get a valid JSON value, and apply a **`SUM()`** aggregation through filtering out the key names `DebtAmount` along with applying ***float*** convertion for the values such as

```sql
 SELECT SUM(value::float)
   FROM t,
LATERAL json_each_text(js)
  WHERE key = 'DebtAmount'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ff1406ceec9acc9036cb011cb2a9d0c8)</kbd>